# Issue with multiple uses of Scanner.nextLine();

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

So, I have some code which, when simplified, is this:

```
import java.util.scanner

private Scanner input; 

int enterInteger()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
    return input.nextInt();
}
String enterString()
{
    return input.nextLine();
}


void main()
{
    System.out.println("Enter option: 1) Add Quantity\n2)Edit Item");
    String input = enterString();
    switch (input)
    {
        case "1":
            enterInteger();
            break;
        case "2":
            //Do whatever
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid!");
            main();
            break;
    }
}
```

So, whenever the user enters the option as 1, it loads enterInteger() that asked the user, and returns, an integer.

However, when this happens, and the user enters the integer and presses enter, the code then begins executing the     `default:` case. When I add a breakpoint the value of option is "", so that's obviously why the `default:` executes, but I can't see how to prevent it.

I know it's something dumb, so thank you.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, adding what I thought were the missing parts, but after I enter my quantity it simply performs the `break` statement in case 1 and exits. Can you post some code we can execute?

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for testing it. Turns out this one oddly worked but the actual code didn't. Reason is that if you're calling nextInt() and then nextLine() (for example typing 1<ENTER>) directly after, it gets "\r\n" as an input as the number is consumed by nextInt()

My own idiocy :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595782/issue-with-multiple-uses-of-scanner-nextline?noredirect=1#comment45500413_28595848

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason yet, But in the past I had to work with only nextLine() and parse with Integer.parseInt() when necessary.

By the way, You haven't initialized the Scanner.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah, the Scanner is initialised in the actual code. I could parse, however some menu options are also alphabetical, so String is necessary.

Comment: Answer, for some odd reason, is:

int enterInteger()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
    return Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
}